# Terraform: How to best loop over a set of directories and apply a gen2 ace block with an azure ad lookup for each iteration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am no expert on terraform by any means, so this may not be technically possible.

My use case is:
I have a adls gen2 file system and I need to create directories in that file system. The directories will, obviously, have a short name and will need to have and ace block (acl) applied to each one. I want some way to associate a directory name to an azure ad group where I can then lookup the group using azuread_group data source and get the object id of the group to apply it to the new directory.

I will try to diagram what I'm trying to do:

```
dir_group_assoc = {
  "folder_name_1": "Azure AD Group 1",
  "folder_name_2": "Azure AD Group 2"
}

data "azuread_group" "group-name" {
  display_name = "Azure AD Group *" <-- replaced with the value from above K/V pair.
}

resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_path" "sftp-root-subdirs" {
  for_each           = toset(["keys from K/V pair above"])
  path               = each.key
  filesystem_name    = azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem.sftp-root.name
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.working-storage_account.id
  resource           = "directory"

  ace {
    scope       = "access"
    type        = "group"
    permissions = "rwx"
    id          = data.azurerm_client_config.current_client_config.object_id["value from K/V pair above"]
  }
}
```

I don't know the best way, if any way, to go about this. I'd love some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I finally came up with that appears to work. I am open to suggestions if this is not the best method, but it got me where I needed to be.

```
variable "folder-ad-group" {
  type = map(string)
  default = {
    "folder_name_1" = "Azure AD Group 1",
    "folder_name_2" = "Azure AD Group 2"
  }
}

data "azuread_group" "ad-group-lookup" {
  for_each     = var.folder-ad-group
  display_name = lookup(var.folder-ad-group, each.key)
}

resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "data-lake-sftp-path" {
  for_each           = data.azuread_group.ad-group-lookup
  name               = each.key
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.working-storage_account.id

  ace {
    scope       = "access"
    type        = "group"
    id          = lookup(data.azuread_group.ad-group-lookup, each.key).object_id
    permissions = "rwx"
  }
}
```

And my output was exactly as you would expect. The ACE blocks looked like:

```
  # azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem.data-lake-sftp-path["folder_name_1"] will be created
  + resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "data-lake-sftp-path" {
      + id                 = (known after apply)
      + name               = "folder_name_1"
      + storage_account_id = "super subscription"

      + ace {
          + id          = "object_id_of_azure_ad_group_1"
          + permissions = "rwx"
          + scope       = "access"
          + type        = "group"
        }
    }

  # azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem.data-lake-sftp-path["folder_name_2"] will be created
  + resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "data-lake-sftp-path" {
      + id                 = (known after apply)
      + name               = "folder_name_2"
      + storage_account_id = "super subscription"

      + ace {
          + id          = "object_id_of_azure_ad_group_2"
          + permissions = "rwx"
          + scope       = "access"
          + type        = "group"
        }
    }
```